# Select features based on distance and threshold value - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, distance, select

Imagine that I have two point feature datasets, being `zero_point` and `points`. I would like use `zero_point` as my input feature to create a selection of points that are 1) as close as possible to `zero_point` and 2) do not exceed a threshold value. To illustrate, I have the following distributions of `zero_point` and `points`:[image]

Assume that my threshold of aggregated values (values are represented by labels) of feature `points` is 10, then the expected output would be:

[image]

How can I realize a selection which is 1) based on distance relative to the input feature AND 2) a certain threshold, preferably using ArcPy?

ArcPy code:

```
#define workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/temp/MyProject-SO_20jan.gdb"

#create empty feature class
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(28992) #Create a spatial reference object.

#create empty point features

## == points == ##
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace, out_name="points", geometry_type="POINT", spatial_reference=sr)
## == zero_point == ##
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace, out_name="zero_point", geometry_type="POINT", spatial_reference=sr)

#add value column to points dataset
fields = [("Value","LONG","4")]

# Create the fields using the above parameters
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management("points", field[0], field[1], "", "",
                              field[2], "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")


#create values with geometry
row_values = [(1, (100000, 30000)), (1, (107000, 30700)), (2, (110000, 40000)),
             (102, (113000, 29000)), (170, (103000, 34070)), (10, (100000, 32070)), (2, (115000, 40000)),
             (502, (110000, 29000)), (5, (108000, 38000)), (1, (107000, 40000))]

#add values to empty feature datasets

## == points ==##

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("points",("Value", "SHAPE@XY"))

for row in row_values:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
    
del cursor

## == zero point == ##

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("zero_point", ["SHAPE@XY"])
xy = (105000, 35000)
cursor.insertRow([xy])

del cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ArcPy I would select all points within your specified distance then *remove from the selection* all points above your threshold, so Select By Location followed by Select By Attribute.

Comment: Your answer assumes a specified distance, however there is no specified distance, only a specified threshold. I think a first step can be to create a "Distance" column in the points dataset which quantifies distance of each point to zero point (this distance can be obtained via a spatial join). Then, sort the dataset by the distance column. Afterwards create an additional column which accumulates the "Value" column. However, an extra step is needed which accumulates values only if it can add up to 10 or less (thereby discarding values such as 10 and 170) but I don't know how to do that exactly